# Converting LaTeX expression to infix expression

Tags: latex, expression, infix-notation

Let us assume we have an expression in LaTeX form:

```
var latex =\frac{x}{\frac{y}{y}}
```

So output required is:

```
output= (x)/((y)/(y));
```

I tried out an example as stated in the link: [Convert LaTeX to dynamic Javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477968/convert-latex-to-dynamic-javascript-function) but I am getting the output of the above latex as:

```
(x)/(\frac{y){y}}`
```

How can I get the expression converted properly? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[solution of the above problem](http://jsfiddle.net/dharmeshpipariya/bddwhnvn/1/)

```
var func = '\frac{x}{\frac{y}{y}}';
func = func.replace(/}{/g, ")/(").replace(/\frac{/g, "(").replace(/}/g, ")")
console.log(func);
```

1. innput = \frac{x}{\frac{y}{y}}
2. output = (x)/((y)/(y))

Comment: Thank you !The best solution till now!