# Is there an easy way to translate LaTeX (MathLive output) into Excel cell formulas in TypeScript/JavaScript or Java?

Tags: javascript, java, excel, typescript, latex

We are using [MathLive](https://mathlive.io/) web component for inputting equations and we need to translate the output (LaTeX) equation into an Excel cell formula.

A simple example would be

> LaTeX
>
> ```
> 0.10632966\times10^{-2}
> ```
>
> Excel Formula
>
> ```
> =0.10632966*10^-2
> ```

and a complicated example would be

> LaTex
>
> ```
> \sqrt[]{\frac{1}{1+1.3448\times-0.74^2}}
> ```
>
> Excel Formula
>
> ```
> =(1/(1+1.3448*-0.74^2))^(1/2)
> ```

Is there a direct way of translating LaTeX strings into Excel cell formulas or at least parse them then build an Excel cell formula out of them using JavaScript/TypeScript or Java?

Comment: There is an old discussion here: [Convert LaTeX to dynamic Javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477968/convert-latex-to-dynamic-javascript-function)

Comment: Also, MathLive is already implementing a complete LaTeX parser in the backround, so you can make use of that to help you. You can browse the [repo](https://github.com/arnog/mathlive/tree/master/src), or look at other output options built into the API such as [`MathJSON`](https://cortexjs.io/guides/math-json/)

Comment: In Java you can try this approach based on "snuggletex":  
- https://github.com/axkr/symja_android_library/blob/master/symja_android_library/matheclipse-core/src/main/java/org/matheclipse/core/form/tex/TeXParser.java 
but it only supports parts of the latex syntax.
Example in the demo: 
- http://matheclipse.org/input?i=ToExpression%28%220.10632966%5C%5C%5C%5Ctimes10%5E%7B-2%7D%22%2C%20TeXForm%29